# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [915, 229] in easy mashine learning sample

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataprofessor/data/master/delaney_solubility_with_descriptors.csv')

X = df.drop('logS', axis=1)
y = df['logS']

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I have a code that tries to predict the logS values. This code is not mine, but from the guide. There are no errors there. So what could be the problem?

```
full error message here:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\AI\test\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "D:\Python\AI\test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\AI\test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 678, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "D:\Python\AI\test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 622, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "D:\Python\AI\test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1164, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "D:\Python\AI\test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 407, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [915, 229]
```

I changed the data-file, and values in ValueError was change too.
I change test_size value, and values in ValueError was change
For test_size = 0.4 :

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [686, 458]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with how you are splitting your data using 'train_test_split'.

You should swap 'y_train' with 'X_test'. See below:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

The correct order is to first specify the features ('X') and then the target variable ('y') for both training and testing datasets.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly refrain from answering questions that are due to **typos**, like this one; leave a comment and flag the question for closure instead.

Comment: @desertnaut I will do that in the future. I was not able to add a comment because I am a new contributor (need 50 points in order to do so).